# NamedPipeBinding not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I am try to used namedPipeBinding in my WCF Service but give a following error.

The protocol 'net.pipe' is not supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The protocol 'net.pipe' is not supported.

My web.config file

services>

```
          <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PipeTest.ICalculatorService" >


              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost"/>
              </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

          <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="PipeTest.ICalculatorService"  />

      </service>
  </services>
```

And i also added "net.pipe" in binding section of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

you lost to add windows activation servive non-http protocol

> control panel -> applications -> windows components

Comment: @chandreshkoyani Mind posting the fix?  Would help those with similar problems.

Comment: @Kenneth Ito he don't install activator it had been issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using full iis.  Can't use cassini (visual studio development server) or IIS express.  They don't support pipes.

If you are using full IIS did you enable the net.pipe protocol?  Right click your site, manage, advanced settings, enabled protocols.  Should be comma delimited no spaces lower case.

Like, "http,net.pipe" for instance

Comment: Yes, I am using full IIS, and also enable net.pipe protocol but still not working. same error.